# AES -256 decryption

Tags: java, aes

I have an encrypted email id for unsubscribing from abcde.test.com.

for ex :  https://abcde.test.com/Forms/unSubscribe.jsp?n=2&rid=00028e7353d9c4eca480a579e10ef09b&eid=588876054d458e62779be9345f399252cac7346ad8c464b8ed0bdfbff3512dd96a5b4190c5d71c30c90c34ff39e544aa

This is encrypted in aes-256.where eid="encrypted message" and rid when combined with keysize,and keystr (like "6a6b663472346c38736873346569727538346234333534376635333962353666") forms the encoded key.

Now I want to decrypt this message.
can any one help me decrypting it?

Comment: Why are you using encryption at all? Where is this URL being generated from - what triggers it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following using Java SE and Apache Commons.  Please note that you haven't indicated the mode or padding for your cipher (just "AES"), so you might need to make some adjustments.

```
// decode the key string into bytes (using Apache Commons)
byte[] keyBytes = Hex.decodeHex(keystr.toCharArray());

// create a representation of the key
SecretKeySpec spec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

// turn the key spec into a usable key
SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("AES");
SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(spec);

// use a cipher to decrypt the eid
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(hex.decodeHex(eid.toCharArray())); // decode from Hex again
```

I don't know what type `eid` represents, so turning that into something concrete is up to you, but here's an example:

```
String eid = new String(plainText, "ASCII");
```

Comment: thanks David.. can you please put the entire code for me,that will truly help alot

Comment: That is the entire code.  Do you mean extracting it from the query string too?

Comment: Hey David.. Following error I got 1> Hex.decode(keyStr); error -Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to byte[]  and 2>  byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(Hex.decode(eid)); error - The method doFinal(byte[]) in the type Cipher is not applicable for the arguments (Object)   What should I do ?

Comment: after type conversion it gave :: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method decode(Object) from the type Hex

Comment: @AbhijeetSinha: I've updated the answer.  You should be able to refer to `keystr` and `eid` as `String` instances now.

Comment: David: I have edited the code it says this exception..Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: AES SecretKeyFactory not available
 at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.<init>(DashoA13*..)
 at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
 at com.motorola.gst.DecryptTest.main(DecryptTest.java:25)

Comment: Apparently this is a bug (http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7022467).  Try passing the `spec` into `cipher.init` instead.

Comment: If I pass spec into cipher.init it gives another exception:: Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
 at com.motorola.gst.DecryptTest.main(DecryptTest.java:31)  Please help me out if there is other solution..

Comment: Like I said in my answer, 'you haven't indicated the mode or padding for your cipher (just "AES"), so you might need to make some adjustments'.  So basically, you need to ask the person who encrypted it, what mode and padding they used.

Comment: encryption mode is CBC and padding is PKCS7